# What are these errors in my Unity project and how do I correct them?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: SCREENSHOT]    si.atlasOffsetX > systemInfo.atlasOffsetX || si.atlasOffsetY > systemInfo.atlasOffsetY

```
terrainInstanceHashes.find (instances[i].instanceID) != terrainInstanceHashes.end ()
```

I have used baked light, terrain and some 3D box objects.

Comment: what errors? post complete if() statetment

Comment: @ŁukaszMotyczka This is an error thrown by Unity in the Console tab.  OP didn't spend  time to ask this question. Just to let you know.

Comment: No script is there. Please look at edit above.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Answer (score 1):

From [this thread](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/global-illumination-computation-unity5-ongoing-saga.306850/), this solution is recommended:

> I managed to find a solution (well, it works for me, at least). I find that if I: 1) clear baked data (you can access that from the "Build" button dropdown on the Lighting panel) and 2) clear the GI cache ( Edit -> Preferences -> GI Cache ) it manages to complete building GI and lightmaps without crashing. However, if you make any changes to your scene and try to re-bake it will crash, unless you take the aforementioned steps.

Comment: This has worked for me, thank you! I'd like to add to this: if your Editor crashes upon startup due to the lighting, what you can do is edit your scene file using an editor like Notepad++ to comment out all of the light objects (simply place a "#" at the beginning of each line related to the lighting objects). This will allow you to open the Editor at least, where you can then apply the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. It seems that ticking off "generating ligthmap UVS" when importing gameobjects was the culprit. I simply turned this off and all of those and the errors would disappear. As for prefabs with this error. You need to turn lightmap static off under the mesh renderer.